# LINQ error to select a column from the table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I got the Error in "context" in Controller using LINQ when i try to get the "value" from JQuery for binding the IDs from 2 different tables based upon the user selection in the dropdownlist

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEmpNo(string value)
    {
        string str = value;
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (value == "Representative")
        {
            // query the tb_RepDetails table and get values.
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list = context.tb_RepDetails.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.RepId }).ToList();
        }
        else if (value == "Agent")
        {
            //query the tb_AgentDetails table and get values.
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list = context.tb_AgentDetails.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.AgentId }).ToList();
        }
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At the begin you declare `items` and then you setting `list` variable you just don't return anything.

It should be:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEmpNo(string value)
    {
        string str = value;
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (value == "Representative")
        {
            // query the tb_RepDetails table and get values.
            items = context.tb_RepDetails.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.RepId }).ToList();
        }
        else if (value == "Agent")
        {
            //query the tb_AgentDetails table and get values.
            items = context.tb_AgentDetails.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.AgentId }).ToList();
        }
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: after i change list to items as your suggestion the same error display like "The name 'context' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Hari that mean you just don't have context variable. Create new instance in tge begining